# Connecting to Amazon s3 from Google App Engine PHP

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I'm working on a PHP application hosted on Google App Engine which requires access to objects stored in an S3 Bucket. I've looked at the APIs available for Amazon S3 and all of them make use of CURL. But CURL is not allowed in Google App Engine. 
Is there a way to access Bucket Contents and user other functions available in the S3 API without using CURL in PHP?

Answer (score 1):

Amazon recently released a wrapper for file_get_contents which is what urlfetch uses - so take a look at http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/php/blog/tag/stream - looks like you can do $contents = file_get_contents("s3://{$bucket}/{$key}");

You should look at the URL Fetch docs - it's the google recommended way to do calls https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/urlfetch/

Answer (score 0):

Use the URL Fetch API instead of CURL

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/urlfetch/

Comment: Yes, I have read about this but couldn't find a way to implement all of the CURL functionality with just URL Fetch.